# How to route to another react component using button in react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm completely new to react and got stuck on the following 'route' part.
Here is the code:

This is my ListEmployeeComponent :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import EmployeeService from '../services/EmployeeService';

class ListEmployeesComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            employees: []
        }
        this.addEmployee = this.addEmployee.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        EmployeeService.getEmployees().then((res) => {
            this.setState({employees: res.data});
        });
    }

    addEmployee() {
        this.props.history.push('add-employee');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2 className="text-center">Employee List</h2>
                <div className="row">
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addEmployee}>Add Employee</button>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Email Id</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        
                        <tbody>
                            {
                                this.state.employees.map(
                                    employee =>
                                    <tr key={employee.id}>
                                        <td>{employee.id}</td>
                                        <td>{employee.firstName}</td>
                                        <td>{employee.lastName}</td>
                                        <td>{employee.email}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ListEmployeesComponent;
```

And this is my App.js :

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import FooterComponent from './components/FooterComponent';
import HeaderComponent from './components/HeaderComponent';
import ListEmployeesComponent from './components/ListEmployeesComponent';
import CreateEmployeeComponent from './components/CreateEmployeeComponent';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <HeaderComponent/>
        <div className="container">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<ListEmployeesComponent/>}></Route>
            <Route path="/home" element={<ListEmployeesComponent/>}></Route>
            <Route path="/add-employee" element={<CreateEmployeeComponent/>}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
        <FooterComponent/>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

My issue is that I want to route to CreateEmployeeComponent when the button gets clicked, but there is no action happening when I click the button. I tried checking the new documentation for react-router v6 but it wasn't much help.
What can I do differently here to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 2):

### **Solution 1:**

You can wrap the button in ListEmployeeComponent using Link from react-router-dom.

```
<Link to="/add-employee">
   <button className="btn btn-primary">Add Employee</button>
</Link>
```

reference: [react-router-dom](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start/1st-example-basic-routing)

### **Solution 2:**

history in react-router-dom **v6** has been replaced by Navigate. So if you want to push **/add-employee** to history you need to use
`<Navigate to='/add-employee' push={true}/>`

Make following changes in your ListEmployeeComponent.js :

add a state in your constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        navigate: false,
        employees: []
    }
    this.addEmployee = this.addEmployee.bind(this);
}
```

change your function:

```
addEmployee() {
   this.props.history.push('add-employee');
}
```

to

```
addEmployee() {
  this.setState({
    navigate: true,
  });
}
```

and change your render method to:

```
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.state;
    if (navigate) {
      return <Navigate to="/add-employee" push={true} />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className="text-center">Employee List</h2>
        <div className="row">
        ........
        //rest of the code
  }
```

reference: [react-router-dom-v6 doc](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navigate)

Comment: The `history` object ***was not*** replaced by a `Navigate` component. Apples and oranges. The `history` object has been abstracted away and replaced by a `navigate` function via the `useHistory` hook. Hooks OFC are not compatible with class-based components, so some additional logic is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to import link in ListEmployeeComponent
and
have to use button tags between link tags
and you have to add [to="/add-employee"] attributes to link tag

```js
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

<Link to="/add-employee"> 
    <button 
        className="btn btn-primary" 
        onClick={this.addEmployee}
    >
        Add Employee
    </button>
</Link>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).